# What are some philosophical arguments that explain why mathematics allow us to reach a greater truth than empirical evidences?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, truth

Is it really the case? Was there a proof of sort that shows mathematical facts are more certain than empirical facts? What are the arguments for and against that claim?

Comment: I think you could ask more specific. I for example don't agree that mathematics > empirics. I think empirics + mathematics > mathematics. The reason is that in order to be useful, it needs empiricism.

Comment: Mathematics is a language, which cannot tell lies. If mathematics says something is true.. it is true. Whether that truth is useful or not, is a different matter. So take gauge algebra which seems to predict particles with 'imaginary' (i, the square root of -1) properties (Tachyons are one such predicted this way). The maths is valid. But do such particles make any sense or is it just Mathematical absurdity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason why mathematical facts are more certain for us than empirical facts:

One can **prove** mathematical theorems.

But nobody could prove general empirical statements, e.g., the laws of nature. In the domain of science, which builds on empirism, we can at best **confirm** our general hypotheses, but all confirmation does not prevent from finding a counter example at a later time.

Comment: But we can prove certain things with controlled experiments like how light behaves under certain conditions since they are reproducible, we can say under the same conditions something will happen.

Comment: @repomonster One can never be sure that by reproducing an experiment all relevant conditions are the same, because one does not know all conditions which are relevant. Every day the Genova-bride was passed by nearly the same nunmber of cars, but one day in 2018 it collapsed.

Comment: Wait, what?? Proving a mathematical theorem tells us NOTHING about the world. Have you looked at the axioms of ZFC? Most of them are demonstrably false about the world. Infinity, Choice, Powerset being the three biggest offenders of reality, but not the only ones. Can you clarify what you mean? Certainly we can use math to model our empirical observations. That's the best you can say.

Comment: @user4894 I think neither the OP nor my answer deal with a relation between mathematics and the physical world. To whom do you address your objection?

Comment: @JoWehler You said, *One can prove mathematical theorems. But nobody could prove general empirical statements*. That seems to be saying that math is more certain than empirical observations. But math is a formal game. Math is no more true than are the laws of chess. Whereas if I drop a bowling ball on my foot, I empirically observe the pain and I thereby discover truth; and if I'm clever, the law of gravity. Is that more clear? I don't see how you can claim you didn't compare and contrast math with empirical observation. You did.

Comment: This is a woefully misinformed answer and shouldn't have been accepted. The example of a bridge collapsing is asinine, "The same amount of cars passing over it" is not a controlled experiment, the bridge was not repaired every single day before the cars drove over it, I can't believe you think that's a good example of "reproducing the same experiment" lmfao.

Comment: @user4894 - Maths is more certain precisely because it is a formal game like chess. It does not rely on induction. You're right to say it can prove nothing about Reality (as Aristotle observes) since reality might not obey the rules, but what it proves it proves with certainty.   .

Comment: @user4894 You are right, mathematics is a formal game. Hence truth in mathematics means logical truth. Of course, that's different from truth about the physical world.

Comment: @JoWehler its not always a different truth otberwise you wouldn't be talking to me now. Maxwells mathematical models of light predicted radio waves... which were subsequently.found empirically. To name just one of hundreds of mathematical predictions that were proven empirically. Like many.things.. with maths if you put rubbish in.. you get rubbish out.. but maths has been accurately predicting reality for 3000 years...

Comment: @Richard One can derive Maxwell's equations from a Lagrange principle by using the rules of calculus. One can decide by proof that the derivation is correct. That's the mathematical truth. But one cannot prove that Maxwell's equation correctly describe electromagnetical phenomena in the physical world of middle dimensions. Of course all observations of classical physics confirm the theoretical predictions, but that's no proof. And indeed, Maxwell's theory has to be replaced by QED to predict phenomena in the micro world.

Comment: @JoWehler well yes..the words 'the orange is in the fruit bowl' do not accurately describe the geospacial locations of the collection of molecules making up.'the orange' either. But my.son doesn't care 'what its like to be a bat', he just wants to know where the orange is. You know... when a philosopher must redefine the word 'absurd' in order to to pretend they are not being absurd.. that... is absurd. Mathematics can.. and does describe reality. It takes a philosopher to say 'i.am lying' aha.. i got you...what if i'm not lying :)